How to import only the extend function of SASS
I want to use only Sass's "@extend" function.
I found the cdn link for Sass, but I don't know how to get and use only the "@extend" function from there.
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/scss/
Can someone tell me how to use "@extend" function via cdn link??
